# Django - limiting url access to superusers

Tags: django, django-urls, currying, django-permissions

In my urlconf, i have:

```
url(r'^sssssh/(.*)', staff_only_app.site.root),
```

What I'd like to do is limiting any access to this application to superusers.
I tried this:

```
url(r'^sssssh/(.*)', user_passes_test(staff_only_app.site.root, lambda u: u.is_superuser)),
```

But it complains that decorate takes exactly 1 argument, and I gave two.

I'm thinking about currying the decorator via functools.partial, but thought I may be missing some more obvious solution.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in urls.py, you should do this in views.py

Comment: @KillianDS I want to do it in urls.py because I don't want to go and edit all the views in a reusable app I didn't write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very late reply!...

I think it's just a quick and dirty syntax hangup:

```
url(r'^sssssh/(.*)', user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)(staff_only_app.site.root),
```

^I think this is the strange but correct syntax for passing an argument to a decorator.

But on 2nd thought, you can only decorate view functions, not entire sites.

Answer (score 1):

Write a decorator similar to Django's login_required or f.ex. this one http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/254/ and decorate the view.

Answer (score 0):

Use the user_passes_test decorator.

example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)

def sample_view(request):
```

Comment: Please, read the question and the comments below it on why I want(ed) to do it in urls and not in views.