# Django - how to use user_pass_test with urls

Tags: python, django, url

I'm trying to use `user_pass_test` in my URL's definitions for CBV and views.

I want to use a similar syntax to this:

```
url (r'^question_detail-(?P<pk>\w+)$', user_passes_test(not_in_group_chef,
login_url='public_connexion')Question_detail.as_view(), name='detail_question')
```

I found :
[Django - limiting url access to superusers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139284/django-limiting-url-access-to-superusers)
and 
http://jonatkinson.co.uk/djangos-user_passes_test-and-generic-views/

But it's not functional in my case.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [django user\_passes\_test decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082670/django-user-passes-test-decorator) See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views for an example of doing it in `urls.py`.

Comment: Thank you but the first link is for CBV on seperate file and the second show login_required and permission_required.
Have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing a pair of brackets in your code example, does this work?

```
url (
    r'^question_detail-(?P<pk>\w+)$',
    user_passes_test(not_in_group_chef, login_url='public_connexion')(
        Question_detail.as_view()
    ),
    name='detail_question'
)
```

Comment: I tried but Django catch error :

DoesNotExist at /question_detail-6
User matching query does not exist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Anentropic was right, thank you !

For someone as the same problem:

The second problem that I solved is: for anonymous users, the not_in_group_chef function should verify if the user is registered. That way you won't get an error for anonymous users.

```
def not_in_group_chef(user):
if user:
    retour = False
    if User.objects.filter(username = user).count()==1:
        utilisateur = User.objects.get(username = user)
        if utilisateur.groups.filter(name='chef').count()==0:
            retour = True
        return retour
    return retour
return False
```

Comment: Django provides a simpler way to check for anonymous users without querying the db: `if user.is_anonymous()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous ...also your `not_in_group_chef` function should be receiving a User/AnonymousUser object, not a username string, so `User.objects.get(username = user)` shouldn't be needed